# Issue in date foarmat in JQuery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have 2 datepicker which binds to textboxes `Chkin` and `Chkout`. I need to display dates in dd/mm/y JQuery datepicker format. Problem is that when I try to get `getFullYear()` method of a `dd/mm/y` formatted date, I get result as of 19th hundred(as I know default starts with 1900). So when ever I select a date in my first datepicker, second date picker year changes to 1913(`August 1913` in month view of August in datepicker 2) what I expected is 2013. 
Below is my code-

```
$("#Chkin").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/y',
    minDate: '+0',
    onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
        if ($("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnDateformat").val() == "dd/mm/y") {

            var parts = dateText.split("/");
            var cin = new Date(Number(parts[2]), Number(parts[1]) - 1, Number(parts[0]));
        } else {
            var cin = new Date(dateText);
        }
        var chkout = new Date(cin.getFullYear(), cin.getMonth(), cin.getDate() + 1);
        var maxCOut = new Date(cin.getFullYear(), cin.getMonth(), cin.getDate() + 7);
        $("#Chkout").datepicker('option', 'minDate', chkout);
        $("#Chkout").datepicker('option', 'maxDate', maxCOut);
        $("#Chkout").datepicker("setDate", chkout);
    }
});
```

Comment: Do a console.log for `cin` and see what it is.

Comment: make a fiddle or show your markup

Answer (score 1):

Check your **system time**.  It must be pointing wrong date.

Also assign datepicker to `Chkout`

```
$("#Chkin, #Chkout").datepicker({ 
  ...
  ...
});
```

check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hGM7F/1/)

Comment: Your JSFiddle is not right, when I slect `28/08/13` in first datepicker, second datepicker date is `09/04/15`. Yeah my system time is correct too..

Comment: But its not coming up for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

It should work for you.

```
jQuery(function($){
  $( "#Chkin" ).datepicker({
      minDate: '+0',
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/y',
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#Chkout" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
    $( "#Chkout" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+0",
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/y',
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#Chkin" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
    var cin = new Date(Number(parts[2]), Number(parts[1]) - 1, Number(parts[0]));
```

to this:

```
var cin = new Date(Number(20 + parts[2]), Number(parts[1]) - 1, Number(parts[0]));
```

Before creating the new date, you must turn it back into a four-digit year, so that the javascript Date() command knows which century to use.